# Mocking Nested Objects with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

We have a class like this :
( Please Note that I do not have the freedom to change the class definition )

```
class X {
  private B b ;
  public X( C c ) {
     b = new B(c ) ;
  }
}
```

How will I write junit test for the above class using Mockito ?

I tried :

```
 class XTest {
        @Mock
        private C c ;
        @InjectMocks
       private X x ;
    ...
    }
```

..Mockito is injecting a mock C. However the line **new B(c)** is throwing an exception as B - which is not a mock -  is not prepared to work with a mock c

Comment: Init mocks and object under test manually instead of relying on annotations. Even better - pass in `B` directly to the constructor of `X`.

Answer (score 1):

No ideas what you are trying to do . If you only want to test X , just mock its direct dependency which is B because from the X 's point of view , you only need to ensure it interacts with B correctly. There is no points to care about how does X interacts with its dependency 's dependency (which is C).

For testing if B interacts with C correctly , it belongs to B 's test case but not X.

So first refactor X such that it can inject B directly through constructor :

```java
class X {
  private B b ;

  public X(B b){
     this.b = b;
  }

   public X(C c) {
     this(new B(c));
  }
}
```

Then your unit test just looks like :

```java
class XTest {

   @Mock
   private B b ;
    
   @InjectMocks
   private X x ; 
}
```

Comment: Please note that I don't have the liberty to change X. I can only write Tests

Comment: Please note that you should mention this constraint in your question. thanks

Comment: and in such case , consider to use reflection to directly configure `X.b` to a mocked `B` . You cannot use `@InjectMocks` due to such constraint.

Comment: ( I just edited the question ) Thank you @ken. Problem is that there is no no-args constructor for X. So Im not even able to create X

Comment: Ok. but this does not prevent you from passing C as null or any dummy C to create a instance of X first. Then use reflection to set X.b to a mocked B

Comment: C cannot be null because new B(c) will throw an exception is c is null

Comment: i don't know as i cannot see the source codes , but  no one prevent you from creating a dummy C for it